# How to stretch image to row height in layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

There're text view and image in one row. I need to stretch image proportionally to be the same height as text view. How to do that?

That's layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:cropToPadding="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use `layout_alignTop` and `layout_alignBottom` to align your views from **Top** and **Bottom** to have the same **Height**

Answer (score 2):

in your ImageView

Try this code

> android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"

instead of

> android:layout_centerVertical="true"

Answer (score 0):

try to use `android:layout_weight`. Weight can only be used in `LinearLayout`

Comment: Layout weight is not what I want: it takes a % from total width. What I need is to take constant height, e.g. weight == 0.0

Comment: wrap your textview, imageview in to linearlayout, and set android:layout_height="fill_parent" for imageview , android:layout_height="wrap_content" for textview

Comment: just use layout_alignTop and layout_alignBottom to align your views from Top and Bottom to have the same Height

Comment: ZuzooVn, your approach is nice, but it works only for Linear layout. I need text view to fill its contents by width (but not image view, so FILL_PARENT doesn't fit here).