# Layout: how to make image to change its width and height proportionally?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have such layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/my_image"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Some text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/my_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/title"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/title"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/my_bitmap_image" />
```

This layout does almost what I need: it makes image view height the same as text view. The image graphic contents stretched also keeping aspect ratio.

**But,**  the width of the image view does **not** change! As a result, I have a wide gap between text and the image view! As a temporal solution, I override `View#onLayout`.

**The question**: how to change image width in xml layout?

**UPDATE:**

This is a final layout I need (text + a few images).
Look at the first image: its width should be exactly the same as scaled image in it with no paddings and margins:

[image]

Comment: What type of Layout you really want? Can you please elaborate it once again with layout screen shots if possible?

Comment: Very good question. I got exactly the same problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, as I see from the answers, there is no solution to force image views to change theirs width and height proportionally.
So, this can be solved only programmatically.
There is my solution below :

a) Create you custom layout class

(don't forget to override all the parent constructors with **public** access modifier, otherwise GUI editor will fail):

```
public class MyLayout extends RelativeLayout {...
```

<del>b) Override method:</del> **Deprecated - changing layout params in this method might cause side effects. See recommended approach below**

`protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {`

`ImageView icon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image);`
      `icon.setMaxWidth(icon.getMeasuredHeight());`

`super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);`

`}`

b) Add creational method:

```
public static MyLayout createLayout(ViewGroup parent) {
Context context = parent.getContext();
MyLayout item = (MyLayout) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
            R.layout.my_layout, parent, false);    
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
ImageView icon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image);
ViewGroup.LayoutParams p = icon.getLayoutParams();
p.width =   (int) tv.getTextSize();;
icon.setLayoutParams(p);
return item;
}
```

c) Final layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.mypackage.MyLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/title"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/my_image"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:singleLine="true"
android:text="Some text"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/my_image"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/title"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/title"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:src="@drawable/my_bitmap_image" />
</com.mypackage.MyLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

For the `imageView` you can add the images to a linearlayout and give the weight property. For example if you have 3 images then give the `linearlayout` weight as `3` and then for each image you give the weight as 1. This way it will be uniformly aligned with equal width for all the images. Make linear orientation as horizontal hope so u got my point.

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:weightSum="3"
     >
   <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_weight ="1" />

    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_weight ="1" />

    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_weight ="1" />
     </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of RelativeLayout, use LinearLayout. You may add "Weight" property to ensure desired spacing.

see the code below

```
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/logonFormButtons"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="true"       
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/logonFormBTLogon"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
        android:text="Some Text"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logonFormBTCancel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
        android:src="@drawable/apk"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this has to do with `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` for your ImageView. Have you tried `layout_toRightOf="@id/title"` ?

Also you can try `android:scaleType="fitStart"` on the ImageView. This should align the image to the top left of the ImageView.

Comment: Have you also removed the `android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/my_image"` from the TextView ?

Comment: Yes, I did it (typing my previous comment).

Answer (score 0):

try to add `scaleType = fitXY` OR `centerInside` property to imageView

Comment: for proportionnal size change, that would be fitCenter

Comment: Image contents are shown correctly. The problem is image view width does not change proportionally to its height changes.

Comment: this is because you have set the imageView's property to android:layout_alignTop="@+id/title"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/title"

Comment: I did so to mae image dimensions to be the same as text height. Could you suggest another solution how to do that without align top/bottom?

Answer (score 0):

As for me I appreciate to change width or height dinamically in my code using getLayoutParams()... for example

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    int wwidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
    convertPixelsToDp(wwidth, getApplicationContext());
//    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), height+ "= "+convertPixelsToDp(height, getApplicationContext()) + 
//          "   " + wwidth+ "= "+convertPixelsToDp(wwidth, getApplicationContext()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   //scroll view 1 screen height size
    scr1 = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.ScrollView01);
    scr1.getLayoutParams().height=height - 200;
```

Comment: My current solution is a little bit better:

    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
  super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
  icon.setMaxWidth(icon.getMeasuredHeight()); 
}

(sorry for problematic code formatting)

Answer (score 0):

put image view in Linear Layout . the give weight to each and every image view.. it will increase the size proportionately ..

Comment: Not quite what I need (shortly, because I need text view FILL_PARENT, but do not overlap images). For details, see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12836075/676369).